# Script the addition of pre-run hooks to Flatpaks

Tags: .desktop, flatpak

I'd like to modify how installed Flatpaks run, so that `podman` containers used by a Flatpak are ran before the Flatpak is run (and ideally shut down after the Flatpak finishes running, but that's optional). The purposes of this is to conserve resources - the `podman` containers don't need to be running all the time.

For example, I'd like to start an `explainshell` container when VSCode is started.

To cover situations when the Flatpaks that are ran from the command line, it's easy - I can just `alias` `flatpak` to a `flatpak-wrapper` script, and then in that `flatpak-wrapper` script, intercept the `flatpak run` invocations that I care about, run the `podman run` commands where necessary, and then run the original requested `flatpak run` commands.

However, `.desktop` files installed by flatpak are trickier, because they contain a hardcoded `/usr/bin/flatpak` invocation, which obviously is unaffected by shell aliases. I can trivially edit those `.desktop` files one by one through the KDE UI, but what if I want to script this editing?

I guess what I need is:

1. a way to find the installed `.desktop` files for a given Flatpak so that I can edit them using a bash script
2. a way to make my edits to such `.desktop` files persistent even after a Flatpak upgrade that changes the `.desktop` file - without requiring any manual steps from the user

(Let's assume that I can't use socket activation because the podman container doesn't support it.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A little bit of spying of my dbus session bus revealed a lot of traffic related to the vscodium Flatpak container. But then after a little Googling, I learned that if systemd is running - which it is for me - *any* Flatpak container will send a message to systemd on startup, which means we can just [use systemd configuration files](https://docs.flatpak.org/en/latest/tips-and-tricks.html) to configure the desired auto-start behaviour.

Here's what I did. This solution illustrates the two possible ways to create a systemd configuration file:

1. a simple file, or
2. a file within in a `.d` directory - which is better for scripts to create, because then they can use a unique filename that won't clash with any other script.

```
[greenrd@fedora ~]$ mkdir .config/systemd/user
```

Generate a systemd `.service` file for the podman container. We override the restart policy to "no" because later our Uphold is going to take care of restarting it.

I'm using `tee` so I can view it before I install it, since I'm doing this manually at the command prompt. In a script, this wouldn't be necessary.

```
[greenrd@fedora ~]$ podman generate systemd --restart-policy=no explainshell |tee es.service
WARN[0000] Container 2f9dd483eed9f6a5705dc142e65c55103c25f8884aa51e3b0e400686f8640b31 has restart policy "always" which can lead to issues on shutdown: consider recreating the container without a restart policy and use systemd's restart mechanism instead 
# container-2f9dd483eed9f6a5705dc142e65c55103c25f8884aa51e3b0e400686f8640b31.service
# autogenerated by Podman 4.5.1
# Fri Jun 16 21:19:03 BST 2023

[Unit]
Description=Podman container-2f9dd483eed9f6a5705dc142e65c55103c25f8884aa51e3b0e400686f8640b31.service
Documentation=man:podman-generate-systemd(1)
Wants=network-online.target
After=network-online.target
RequiresMountsFor=/run/user/1000/containers

[Service]
Environment=PODMAN_SYSTEMD_UNIT=%n
Restart=no
TimeoutStopSec=70
ExecStart=/usr/bin/podman start 2f9dd483eed9f6a5705dc142e65c55103c25f8884aa51e3b0e400686f8640b31
ExecStop=/usr/bin/podman stop  \
        -t 10 2f9dd483eed9f6a5705dc142e65c55103c25f8884aa51e3b0e400686f8640b31
ExecStopPost=/usr/bin/podman stop  \
        -t 10 2f9dd483eed9f6a5705dc142e65c55103c25f8884aa51e3b0e400686f8640b31
PIDFile=/run/user/1000/containers/overlay-containers/2f9dd483eed9f6a5705dc142e65c55103c25f8884aa51e3b0e400686f8640b31/userdata/conmon.pid
Type=forking

[Install]
WantedBy=default.target
```

Let's remove the autostart on boot behaviour:

```
[greenrd@fedora ~]$ sed -i -e '/WantedBy=default\.target/d' es.service
```

And remove the restart configuration, since `Upholds` below is supposed to handle that:

```
[greenrd@fedora ~]$ sed -i -e '/Restart=/d' es.service
```

Looks OK - let's install it:

```
[greenrd@fedora ~]$ mv es.service .config/systemd/user/explainshell.service
```

And add the dependency relationship - I found the scope using [bustle](https://gitlab.freedesktop.org/bustle/bustle):

```
[greenrd@fedora ~]$ cat <<EOF >.config/systemd/user/app-com.vscodium.codium-.scope.d/my-ublue.conf
> [Unit]
Upholds=explainshell.service
> EOF
```

Finally, make systemd aware of our new config files:

```
[greenrd@fedora ~]$ systemctl --user daemon-reload
```

OK, that works, but the container stays around after vscodium exits:

```
[greenrd@fedora ~]$ podman ps
CONTAINER ID  IMAGE                                    COMMAND               CREATED       STATUS             PORTS                   NAMES
9b733a307e42  quay.io/fedora/fedora:38                 -v --name greenrd...  2 days ago    Up 2 days                                  fedora
ef21c84a47eb  ghcr.io/ublue-os/boxkit:latest           -v --name greenrd...  2 days ago    Up 2 days                                  boxkit
2f9dd483eed9  ghcr.io/idank/idank/explainshell:master  make serve            45 hours ago  Up About a minute  0.0.0.0:5000->5000/tcp  explainshell
```

Actually, vscodium is not quite dead. There are some zombie processes and some other processes still hanging around. Odd. Let's kill them:

```
[greenrd@fedora ~]$ killall codium
[greenrd@fedora ~]$ killall codium
[greenrd@fedora ~]$ killall -KILL codium
codium: no process found
```

But the explainshell container is still there:

```
[greenrd@fedora ~]$ podman ps
CONTAINER ID  IMAGE                                    COMMAND               CREATED       STATUS        PORTS                   NAMES
9b733a307e42  quay.io/fedora/fedora:38                 -v --name greenrd...  2 days ago    Up 2 days                             fedora
ef21c84a47eb  ghcr.io/ublue-os/boxkit:latest           -v --name greenrd...  2 days ago    Up 2 days                             boxkit
2f9dd483eed9  ghcr.io/idank/idank/explainshell:master  make serve            45 hours ago  Up 3 minutes  0.0.0.0:5000->5000/tcp  explainshell
```

To attempt to fix this, I tried to add

```
After=explainshell.service
PropagatesStopTo=explainshell.service
```

to `my-ublue.conf`. However, unfortunately, the initial scope that Flatpak creates is transient, so it gets stopped and immediately causes the explainshell container to be stopped too. So I couldn't get the container to shut down automatically, but this was an optional requirement.